# Searchable content not appearing in search results

Tags: search, channel-fields, index

I've got an existing site, and recently changed the settings of a few Channel Fields to make them searchable.

There are lots of pages using the Channel already, so I was hoping that my change to the channel fields would make all that content searchable immediately, but this hasn't been the case. I've also tried editing and saving a page (in case that triggered a new index) but that hasn't worked either.

I can't find how to reset or rebuild the search index to include this content. Any pointers much appreciated!

T

Comment: Are you getting any results what so ever? Did you set which field to use as the excerpt in the search results in the channel settings?

Comment: I'm getting results from other Channels, but not this new channel. It is quite possible I've not set up the channel correctly to show results. All I've done is changed a channel fields setting to 'is searchable'. Its been some time since I set this site up (or any EE one for that matter) and I can't find any instruction on how to retro fit search to a new Channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was user error as I feared. In order to make a new channel searchable I needed to change the channel="" parameter on my simple search form to include the new channel.

```
   {exp:search:simple_form channel="originalchannel|newlysearchablechannel" form_class="search-form" results="14" result_page="/search/results" no_result_page="/search/no_results" search_in="entries"}
                <label for="search">Search</label>        
                <input type="search" id="search" name="keywords" placeholder="SEARCH" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Thanks to Mark for the steer that I needed to make more changes than I had.